# Why does GTK+ define TRUE and FALSE?

Tags: c, gtk

Why do GTK+ and several other frameworks provide `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros? Is there any advantage to using `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of the built-in C values `true` and `false`? You can see their implementation here: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Standard-Macros.html#TRUE:CAPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99 has `true` and `false`, earlier versions do not.  That is why you often see `TRUE` and `FALSE` `#define`d.  As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627178/c99-why-are-false-and-true-defined-as-0-and-1-and-not-as-bool0-and-bool), `true` and `false` are `1` and `0` respectively, same as `TRUE` and `FALSE`.