# Is true == 1 && false == 0 always true in C?

Tags: c

There are many questions of this kind on SO so I apologize for this additional one.

`stdbool.h` defines this:

```
#define true  (1)
#define false (0)
```

However I've seen many other declarations in *bad* code such as

```
#define true  (0xFF)
#define false (!true)
```

Or even worse

```
#define true  (0xAAAAAAAA)
#define false (~true)
```

In a real context we could imagine a variable `int istrue` used somewhere in a bad C program:

```
istrue = 1;
```

Because the code I am looking at is pretty ugly, I cannot assume I won't see things like:

```
if (istrue == 1)
```

That will make me refrain from replacing `istrue = 1` with `istrue = true`.

So my question is:

In C, is `true` always equal to `1` and `false` always equal to `0` for any C compiler, and should this assumption always be valid in any case?

Comment: Every non zero value is TRUE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627178/c99-why-are-false-and-true-defined-as-0-and-1-and-not-as-bool0-and-bool

Comment: Actually not. in C bool are integer, then all number != 0 are true

Comment: @Dayalrai Perfectly right, but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This link answer the case for C99 not for any C compiler or programming methodology

Comment: In C, it is idiomatic to simply use `if (!x)` or `if (x)`. The only reasonable use for `true/false` is in loop conditions like `while (true) {}` or `do {} while (false);`.

Comment: @EOF: note that `while (true) {}` is UB in C.

Comment: @Bathsheba: *sigh*. This was a *comment*. So I really need to write `while (true) {...}` to show that there is supposed to be code there? If I didn't want the loop to do anything (indeed being undefined), I'd write `while (true);`.

Comment: @EOF - what about bool returnValue = false; ?

Comment: @LPs In C - for the past 16 years, boolean variables are type `_Bool`, not `int`.

Comment: @chux Yes, you right. Probably is the sign I'm a little bit seasoned...

Comment: But is it safe to say "c += (x > 0);" as opposed to "if (x > 0) c++;"